# How to use return methods, parameter passing with arrays in java

Tags: java

I was wondering if it is possible to use return methods and parameter passing to carry out processing in arrays in java. Obviously, i am not following the right steps. I am not sure whether it is possible or not.

The purpose of my code is to ask the user to enter a specific number of letters. The user will then enter the data, which will be translated into english. The issue is, i wish to carry out the processing using a return method, if it is at all possible.

Thanks! I would very much appreciate any help

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*; //gives access to java command libraries
import hsa.*; //gives access to console class file
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class work
{
    Console c; //The output console

    int numberOfLetters = 0;
    String[] userInput = new String [numberOfLetters];
    String[] translatedData;
    String english[] = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "/", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"};
    String morse[] = {".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--..", "/", "-----", ".----", "..---", "...--", "....-", ".....", " -....", "--...", "---..", "----."};


    //It is the class constructor of a java program
    public work ()
    {
        c = new Console (""); //creates a new console object window
    }


    public void morseFile ()
    {
        title ();
        c.print ("Please enter the number of letters you wish to enter: ");
        numberOfLetters = c.readInt ();
        userInput = new String [numberOfLetters];
        translatedData = new String [numberOfLetters];
        c.println ("");
        c.println ("Please enter the morse data you wish to translate ");

        int line = 0;

        do
        {
            c.print ("Enter morse letter " + (line + 1) + ": ");
            userInput [line] = c.readString ();
            line++;
        }
        while (line < numberOfLetters)
            ;

        for (int i = 0 ; i < userInput.length ; i++)
        {
            if (!(userInput [i].equals ("/") || userInput [i].equals (".-") || userInput [i].equals ("-...") || userInput [i].equals ("-.-.") || userInput [i].equals ("-..") || userInput [i].equals (".") || userInput [i].equals ("..-.") || userInput [i].equals ("--.") || userInput [i].equals ("....") || userInput [i].equals ("..") || userInput [i].equals (".---") || userInput [i].equals ("-.-") || userInput [i].equals (".-..") || userInput [i].equals ("--") || userInput [i].equals ("-.") || userInput [i].equals ("---") || userInput [i].equals (".--.") || userInput [i].equals ("--.-") || userInput [i].equals (".-.") || userInput [i].equals ("...") || userInput [i].equals ("-") || userInput [i].equals ("..-") || userInput [i].equals ("...-") || userInput [i].equals (".--") || userInput [i].equals ("-..-") || userInput [i].equals ("-.--") || userInput [i].equals ("--..") || userInput [i].equals (".----") || userInput [i].equals ("..---") || userInput [i].equals ("...--") || userInput [i].equals ("....-") || userInput [i].equals (".....") || userInput [i].equals ("-....") || userInput [i].equals ("--...") || userInput [i].equals ("---..") || userInput [i].equals ("----.") || userInput [i].equals ("-----") || userInput [i].equals ("/")))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Please enter the right input");
                morseFile ();
            }
        }

        c.println ("");
        c.print ("The translated data is: ");
        c.println ("");
    }


    private String translated (String[] translatedData)
    {
        translatedData = new String [numberOfLetters];
        c.print ("THE NUMBER OF LETTERS IS: " + numberOfLetters);
        for (int i = 0 ; i < userInput.length ; i++)
        {
            if (userInput [i].equals ("a") || userInput [i].equals ("b") || userInput [i].equals ("c") || userInput [i].equals ("d") || userInput [i].equals ("e") || userInput [i].equals ("f") || userInput [i].equals ("g") || userInput [i].equals ("h") || userInput [i].equals ("i") || userInput [i].equals ("j") || userInput [i].equals ("k") || userInput [i].equals ("l") || userInput [i].equals ("m") || userInput [i].equals ("n") || userInput [i].equals ("o") || userInput [i].equals ("p") || userInput [i].equals ("q") || userInput [i].equals ("r") || userInput [i].equals ("s") || userInput [i].equals ("t") || userInput [i].equals ("u") || userInput [i].equals ("v") || userInput [i].equals ("w") || userInput [i].equals ("x") || userInput [i].equals ("y") || userInput [i].equals ("z") || userInput [i].equals ("0") || userInput [i].equals ("1") || userInput [i].equals ("2") || userInput [i].equals ("3") || userInput [i].equals ("4") || userInput [i].equals ("5") || userInput [i].equals ("6") || userInput [i].equals ("7") || userInput [i].equals ("8") || userInput [i].equals ("9") || userInput [i].equals ("/"))
            {
                for (int z = 0 ; z < english.length ; z++)
                {
                    if (userInput [i].equals (english [z]))
                    {
                        translatedData [i] = morse [z];
                        return translatedData [i];
                    }

                }
            }
            else if (userInput [i].equals (".-") || userInput [i].equals ("-...") || userInput [i].equals ("-.-.") || userInput [i].equals ("-..") || userInput [i].equals (".") || userInput [i].equals ("..-.") || userInput [i].equals ("--.") || userInput [i].equals ("....") || userInput [i].equals ("..") || userInput [i].equals (".---") || userInput [i].equals ("-.-") || userInput [i].equals (".-..") || userInput [i].equals ("--") || userInput [i].equals ("-.") || userInput [i].equals ("---") || userInput [i].equals (".--.") || userInput [i].equals ("--.-") || userInput [i].equals (".-.") || userInput [i].equals ("...") || userInput [i].equals ("-") || userInput [i].equals ("..-") || userInput [i].equals ("...-") || userInput [i].equals (".--") || userInput [i].equals ("-..-") || userInput [i].equals ("-.--") || userInput [i].equals ("--..") || userInput [i].equals (".----") || userInput [i].equals ("..---") || userInput [i].equals ("...--") || userInput [i].equals ("....-") || userInput [i].equals (".....") || userInput [i].equals ("-....") || userInput [i].equals ("--...") || userInput [i].equals ("---..") || userInput [i].equals ("----.") || userInput [i].equals ("-----") || userInput [i].equals ("/"))
            {

                for (int z = 0 ; z < morse.length ; z++)
                {
                    if (userInput [i].equals (morse [z]))
                    {

                        translatedData [i] = (english [z]);
                        return translatedData [i];
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }

    public void display ()
    {
        c.print ("The translated data is: " + translated (translatedData));
    }


    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        work h = new work ();
        h.morseFile ();
        h.display ();

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `return method`?

Comment: use the return method in java to return a specific value

Comment: You're using return values in `translated()`. What is your question?

Comment: the issue is, the values are not being returned properly and i receive an error message. I am not sure whether or not i can return values in arrays in java. If so, what steps should i follow.

Comment: You can return an array. Try to make yourself a small example program to call a method that returns an array to see how it works. Debugging a complicated program, especially on a website without seeing the error message, is difficult!

Comment: *"the issue is, the values are not being returned properly and i receive an error message."*.  Please be more specific.  What do you mean by "values are not being returned properly"?  What error message are you getting?

Comment: *"How to use return methods"* ... So do you actually mean a `return` **statement**?

Comment: I really appreciate all of your help! The issue is, i really have no idea of how to return the array, i am a really a beginner in java. So i was wondering if there was a way to use the return method within an array. And i have been trying to return values within an array for quite a few days, without any success

Comment: Are you trying to return an array, or an element within an array? As it stands, it's not clear what you're trying to do, or what problems you're facing, and your question is likely to be closed.

Comment: i apologize for the lack of clarity. Within the method **translated ()**, **translatedData [i] = (english [z])**; is within the if statement. I wish to **return translatedData [i]**. And at this stage, i have no idea of how to return translatedData [i]

Answer (score 0):

A method that returns an array would be declared and coded like this, with adjustments for whatever you're actually trying to do (and this would have to be within a class, of course, there is no such thing as a free-floating method in Java):

```
public String[] getNames() 
{
  String[] names = { "Alfred", "Willy", "Teddy", "Fred" };
  return names;
}
```

Those are the essentials -- the method must be declared to return an array of a specific type (int, String, a class of your own creation, all are legal). You declare a variable of the correct type (array of String, in this case), and return it with the data it's supposed to have.

In order to use such a method, then, a different method would need an instance of whatever class contained this method; call it class NameGenerator:

```
NameGenerator ng = new NameGenerator();
// ...
String[] generatedNames = ng.getNames();
```

Again, this would have to be within a class, and within a method in that class.

Note that no specific number of elements has to be declared when using the method; If you are using the "initializer" form of putting elements in the array, no specific number of elements needs to be declared there either.

Is that what you were after?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, this is not what i am after. If you look in my code, the main issue i have is return translatedData [i], and i would like to ask how would i be able to **return translatedData [i]** within the code. I appreciate the help though.

Comment: I think part of the confusion here is that your code *already* returns `translatedData[i]`, and syntactically does it correctly. The method is declared to return a String, `translatedData` is declared as an array of string, and you have a return statement that would return one string out of the array. I gather each String in that array is one letter. So we who are trying to help don't know what you're after. We don't know what the error is; copy it and put it in the question (don't tell us what it is in different words).

Comment: right, sorry for not being clear. **Error: A return statement with expression must be contained in a method declaration that is declared to return a value** . Question: I believe that i have entered everything syntactically correct, and then why am i receiving the issue?

Comment: A note about SO questions: when you have an error, include the text of the error. This is *part* of the text of the error. It is a compile error, and those always have the line number and the name of the file with them, so I know you have given the part that you feel is relevant instead of the whole thing. But if you really understood what was relevant, you wouldn't have the question. So give the entire message, and (since it is compilation), the entire file referred to, AND indicate the line named in the line number. If you cannot see the error at that point, someone here can.